# Why would I not be able to view all websites over wireless, but can over wired networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wired-networking

At home I'm running a wireless hop network, and can't seem to visit some websites, but when I'm over my wireless hop I can access any website.  Why is this happening?

Comment: You need to provide a LOT more information before anyone can provide a meaningful answer.  What works, what doesn't.  How is your network configured ? What is a "wireless hop network " - that is not a technical term I've come across before, and I've been quite involved in wireless netoworks. ?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. You say first "wireless hop network, and can't seem to visit some websites" and then "wireless hop I can access any website". Both of these cannot be correct at the same time.

Comment: A wireless hop is like a wired hop on a network, but two wireless routers are talking to each other.  You can set some parental controls on one MAC address, but not on another, which is similar to only allowing some MAC addresses to access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to the network administrator, I found out that it's the anti-hacker settings, like the firewall, and parental controls (which also blocks Stack Overflow).